# Missing Private Key after updating Node

Tags: node.js, encryption, rsa, upgrade, node-crypto

I'm having an issue maintaining a legacy system where I have to upgrade from Node 10 to Node 20, although I've isolated the problem to after upgrading to node 12.

The issue is with the crypto privateDecrypt method, which worked fine when in node 10, but in node 12 gives the error:

`error:040650B3:rsa routines:rsa_ossl_private_decrypt:missing private key`

and then by node 20 gives the slightly different error:

`error:020000B3:rsa routines::missing private key`

Here is the code needed to repro the issue:

```
    message = fs.readFileSync(`input`)
  
    const decrpyted = crypto.privateDecrypt({
      key: fs.readFileSync(`stats.pem`),
      padding: crypto.constants.RSA_PKCS1_PADDING
    }, message);

    
    res.send(decrpyted);
```

(It doesn't really matter what the message is because the missing key error appears before it tries to decrypt it, so if I get far enough that it fails on the decryption its still progress!)

Unfortunately I suspect it may be an issue with the key I'm using, but I cant provide that (because, you know, it's private) - and I also cannot create a new key pair, because too many systems have the old public key embedded that we can't change.

Any suggestion on where to go next would be appreciated!

---

*Edits*:

The .pem file looks like:

```
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
...
...
...
-----END PRIVATE KEY-----
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
...
...
...
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

Comment: Have you checked whether it is a valid private key? Such a message occurs (on v21.2.0), e.g. if a public key is used instead of a private key.

Comment: The .pem contains the BEGIN PRIVATE KEY / END PRIVATE KEY messages, and it also used to work on v10, so I assume it must be valid? Is there any other way to confirm it?

Comment: You can check the key with openssl (openssl rsa -in <your key> -check) or analyze it with an ASN.1 parser.

Comment: If your PEM file really contains both, private key and certificate, I would store key and certificate in different files and try the decryption with the private key alone.

Comment: OK, so Openssl says it's good regardless of whether it also contains the certficate or not.

If I remove the certificate, the error from the repro  app becomes "pkcs decoding error" which seems like progress, and is expected as I'm not using a valid message. 
I'm going to try it in the main app so it's working with actual data - and hopefully this works!

Comment: Thankyou for your help @Topaco - this worked :D

Now I just need to figure out if anything was relying on that certificate being there - but that should be easier, thankyou very much!